# How to run trained Yolov3 model with using GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, yolo, custom-object

I'm a newbie in DL/Real time object detection area and tring to learn some stuff from youtube. I watched a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLngCtsG3bk on youtube about real time custom object detection on yolov3 and I did all stepts correctly. When I run my object-detection python file on my laptop its running on CPU and I can only receive 2-3 fps. Please can anyone tell me how can I use my GPU for running it. The files I got `yolov3_training_last.weights`, `yolov3_testing.cfg` and `classes.txt`. The python file is included below and when I run it as I said I get low fps. If  is there any way to increase it with using GPU, please teach me. Thank you in advance.

Python File:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

net = cv2.dnn.readNet('yolov3_training_last.weights', 'yolov3_testing.cfg')

classes = []
with open("classes.txt", "r") as f:
    classes = f.read().splitlines()

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
colors = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(100, 3))

# used to record the time when we processed last frame
prev_frame_time = 0
 
# used to record the time at which we processed current frame
new_frame_time = 0

while True:
    _, img = cap.read()
    height, width, _ = img.shape

    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1/255, (416, 416), (0,0,0), swapRB=True, crop=False)
    net.setInput(blob)
    output_layers_names = net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames()
    layerOutputs = net.forward(output_layers_names)

    boxes = []
    confidences = []
    class_ids = []

    for output in layerOutputs:
        for detection in output:
            scores = detection[5:]
            class_id = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[class_id]
            if confidence > 0.95:
                center_x = int(detection[0]*width)
                center_y = int(detection[1]*height)
                w = int(detection[2]*width)
                h = int(detection[3]*height)

                x = int(center_x - w/2)
                y = int(center_y - h/2)

                boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
                confidences.append((float(confidence)))
                class_ids.append(class_id)

    indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.2, 0.4)

    if len(indexes)>0:
        for i in indexes.flatten():
            x, y, w, h = boxes[i]
            crop_img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            (B, G, R) = [int(x) for x in cv2.mean(crop_img)[:3]]
            roi_face= img[y: y+ h, x:x+w]
            roi_face = cv2.blur(roi_face,(20,20))
            img[y: y+ h, x: x+ w]=[0,0,0]
            img[y: y+ h, x: x+ w]=cv2.add(roi_face, img[y: y+ h, x: x+ w])
            label = str(classes[class_ids[i]])
            confidence = str(round(confidences[i],2))
            color = colors[i]
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), color, 2)
            cv2.putText(img, label + " " + confidence, (x, y+20), font, 1, (255,255,255), 2)

    
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    # time when we finish processing for this frame
    new_frame_time = time.time()
 
    # Calculating the fps
 
    # fps will be number of frame processed in given time frame
    # since their will be most of time error of 0.001 second
    # we will be subtracting it to get more accurate result
    fps = 1/(new_frame_time-prev_frame_time)
    prev_frame_time = new_frame_time
 
    # converting the fps into integer
    fps = int(fps)
 
    # converting the fps to string so that we can display it on frame
    # by using putText function
    fps = str(fps)
 
    # putting the FPS count on the frame
    cv2.putText(img, fps, (7, 70), font, 3, (100, 255, 0), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)

    cv2.imshow('Image', img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key==27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to install a version of `Tensorflow` that supports GPU. you then have to specify which device to use, either your CPU or GPU.

Plus your GPU must be able to run the program. So You need to install related libraries. if you have `AMD` GPU it will be hard since they  dont support `Tensorflow` GPU i guess. As for `Nvidia` there are drivers and libraries for it.

Your other option is using `Pytorch`, which again you need to have the correct hardware and software.

Another way is creating the model from scratch using `Keras` and `PlaidML`

Comment: I have GTX 1650 and Intel Core i7 9750H. Please can you provide a link or can you tell me how can I do them. I have tensorflow in my laptop.

Comment: Follow the guide [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) it shows which software you need to install

Comment: Sir, I already have all of them as I said. Just I want to know where can I find a python file that runs with GPU version and do I need to do anything like convertion my weights file to another file or etc. The main question is: How can I run real time object detection with using my files?

Comment: And There is an interesting example [here] (https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-perform-object-detection-with-yolov3-in-keras/) that uses `keras` and `yolo3` for detection. good luck